# convert NSButton with text to NSButton with image swift

Tags: swift

I have a button that has a text label. I would like to use a image for my Asset directory instead however I am not sure how

current code block

```
 if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
      button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
      button.title = "ELMC Bridge"
    }
```

What I have tried to get image as button label

```
 if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
      button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
      button.image:("logo132")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setimage propery:

```
if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
    button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
    let image = NSImage(named: "logo132")
    button.setImage(image)
}
```